# Why is my app crashing when I change my spinner selection?

Tags: java, android

My App is crashing when I try to change my drop down spinner selected item.

What I am trying to do is have a bunch of ImageViews that change images depending on what is selected by the spinner.

It works fine on my Galaxy s7 but my s4 crashes every time I switch the spinner

I'm using a switch case method to do it like this.. Just assume all of my variables are already named and initialized correctly.

```
public void example(){
    switch(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()){

         case "A":
            imageview.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a);
            break; 
    } 
}
```

I am doing this for 7 images in one switch case method and have two of these methods because I have two columns of images.

I am using an array adapter  and assigning it to my spinner,
then I am calling the method like this:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView2, View view2, int i2, long l2) {

            example();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

thanks for any help I don't know why it is crashing on my s4 and not my s7

Comment: check your logs

Comment: And show them here =)
In addition, you should better use _drawable_ folder for your images, because a _mipmap_ folder is used for application icon for launcer, not for usual images in your app.

Comment: please attach error logs

Comment: S7 has much more memory than S4. Bitmaps consume memory very fast. It's probably a memory error

Comment: I think you are right cricket_007

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution of your problem. Change your example function with below function:

```
public void example(String string){
 switch(string){
    case "A":
    imageview.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a);
    break; } 
 }
```

And slight change here to solve it:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView2, View view2, int i2, long l2) {
        String string = adapterView2.getSelectedItem().toString()
        example(string);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you. this did not fix the crashing but I'm sure it helps. I think it's like he said that it's a memory problem as I am a beginner and I used .jpg instead of .png which is probably better to use right?

Comment: Share logcat datat for solving your crashing